# Suggestion needed: one content type per custom list or multipe content type within one custom list

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, custom-list

I am here to get your advise and opinion.
As well as the Pro's and Con's for each option you suggest.

A custom list within SharePoint allows you to create a list whereby you can generate / design a form to collect certain data. The custom list also allows you to enable the **Content Type** which means you can create different forms by sharing the same column names.

For example: I got 5 paper forms (Absence Request, Holiday Request etc.) which I like to implement into SharePoint to safe paper but as well as have a better process / structure.

Here we have 2 options:

1) either we create 5 different custom lists 
2) or we enable content type and create 5 different types within 1 custom list.

**What is the catch / problem?!**

I am still a newbie with SP and still learn new stuff as going along :) and I came across an article about the 5.000 limit threshold in SharePoint!

What is your opinion about such implementation: should I stick one custom list per form (individually) or rather have all forms within ONE custom list.?!

Will this cause any issues in the future ?!
I am in planning things ahead and don't want to regret this after a while.

Answer (score 2):

I say it all usually comes down to permissions. If you think that the content types will have different permissions from another content type, you'd be well advised to separate them out into different libraries. Also I'd separate them out if the columns are vastly different.

If they are all the same permissions and mostly the same columns, I'd say keep one library and different content types. Note that in order to filter them in/out with a view is relatively easy.

Another idea is, what about making the "content type" just a column, such as "Reason for Leave" and having values such as `Vacation`, `Sick`, `Bereavement`, etc.

Comment: Hello Mike, the purpose of the forms are so staff members can raise (make requests) online and then it goes through approval process. Indeed, each user cannot see everybody's requests but their own - however, managers or even HR Personnel will then be able to see "all" their staff members requests. hmmm maybe this be a better idea to seepage them??

Comment: as per the values (I call them columns) they will be a lot of used across the content types, such as 'Name' , 'department' or 'username' etc.

Comment: important question is; how about the 5000 threshold limit ? will this not be an issue in such case.... ?!

Comment: 5000 item limit can be easily rectified by indexing columns and creating filtered views from them.

Comment: assume I got 6K of content type: Holiday Request. How would you then rectify the indexing / columns in a view ?

Comment: make several of the columns indexed, and then create a view on that column, irrespective of content type.

Comment: sorry, I fail to understand (picture it in my head) :(

Comment: Add index column: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-index-to-a-SharePoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0 then create a view: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-filtering-to-modify-a-SharePoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create 5 different custom lists.

Because there is a 5000 List view threshold specifies the maximum number of list or library items that a database operation, such as a query, can process at the same time outside the daily time window set by the administrator during which queries are unrestricted.

Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493258(v=office.16).aspx